# SSRS pie chart Values don't add to 100% because of rounding

Tags: reporting-services

I have difficulty to display the correct percentage on pie chart  because SSRS   rounding the decimal Causing  the pie char percentage  Items sum to go up above 100%.

Ex  7.969     expecting  7.96  but getting 7.97

Comment: why are you "expecting" those values.. it's mathing correctly!

Comment: This cause when all the items  percentage added greater than 100%

Comment: show your whole dataset